# Jenkins for syncing folder in separate environments

Tags: unix, jenkins, legacy-code

We have a legacy system whose code files are stored in a proprietary (binary) format.

You cannot modify them unless:

1. You use the proprietary editor, which is awful
2. You export the code to a text file, do your changes using any text editor, then import the code back to it's original format. Any attempt to modify the binary files outside the official editor will corrupt them.

Also, any developer who want to work on the code in their Windows machines must:

1. Log into their unix account through terminal.
2. Use a shell script to convert the binary to text.
3. Download the text file to Windows through FTP.
4. Code using their preferred editor.
5. Upload finished code, again through FTP, to the unix server.
6. Use another shell script to convert text to binary format.

Now to my question(s):

Let's say the developers has all the code converted to text in a predefined folder in their machines.  Is it possible to configure Jenkins to automatically upload any changes made to their unix account and convert back into binary? And vice versa.

I am currently working on this, but my solution implies installing a script/service which will run continuously in the developers' machines.

I would prefer this other solution, with the goal of in the future starting a CI/CD pipeline from it.

Answer (score 2):

Use any version control system to store code in text format.
Developers will pull, do job and push changes, all in text format.
In Jenkins create job, use **Build Triggers** to convert to binaries on any changes in version control system. Copy binaries where needed.